# How to use sparql to filter out values depends on results of a subquery

Tags: sparql, jena

this is my query:

```
PREFIX kg: <http://somecompany.com/KnowledgeGraph/Property/>

SELECT ?dish ?m ?m2
WHERE
    {
        ?dish kg:materials ?m .
        FILTER(?m != ?m2)
        {
            SELECT ?m2
               WHERE {
                  ?ddd kg:foodId ?d
                  FILTER(?d IN (117016813, 116802606)) .
                  ?ddd kg:materials ?m2 .
               }
        }
} LIMIT 100
```

It didn't work because of it only filter out one of the results of subquery but not all of them. So how can I construct the query which match my requirement?

And sorry for my poor written English :)

Comment: `SELECT ?dish ?m ?m2
WHERE
    {?dish kg:materials ?m . filter not exists {?ddd kg:foodId ?d
                  FILTER(?d IN (117016813, 116802606)) .
                  ?ddd kg:materials ?m .}} limit 100`

Comment: in general, [negation in SPARQL 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#negation) either with `NOT EXISTS` or `MINUS`